# How to set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy

Tags: html, google-chrome, oauth

I am using Google sites for building a site. I am embedding a Google Sign-in button with HTML code. The button is shown, but after clicking on it I get a blank screen. Devtools console shows an error:
*[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.*
I have found an explanation of this problem where it is advised to set *Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy* to  *same-origin-allow-popups*. But I don't know how to do this. Is it done in HTML? Or is it a setting in the browser (Chrome)?

Comment: same issue, running basic html file in browser with google sso also show console error given origin is not allowed.
and when clicked the google button, it just open a blank page